# scrapy close reason in pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I use scrapy pipelines to save items in db and it works fine for this purpose. Now I'm try to write in db a record with spider closed reason. When I raise CloseSpider exception I can yield specific item before raise (and save record to db). But if spider closed with "finished" I can't do same thing.
What I tried:

1. make connect spider_closed signal to spider_closed method inside
   spider method and yield item from there - that is not working
2. inside spider_closed set some spider variable to reason value and
       then try to read it in pipeline's close_spider method. The problem
       here is that pipeline's close_spider called before spider's
       spider_closed. And also there is no reason param in pipeline's
       close_spider signature: close_spider(self, spider)
3. Working solution which I have now - direct execute query inside
   spider's spider_closed. But I want to avoid that and separate my db logic from spider logic

So, can anyone provide me how to access spider close reason inside pipeline?

UPD:
Thank's to [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572383/paul-trmbrth) I register signal handler inside pipeline from_crawler method (almost like inside spider) and it works for me

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    temp = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(temp.spider_closed, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
    return temp

def spider_closed(self, reason):
    logging.info("REASON: {}".format(reason))
```

Comment: What about registering a handler for [spider_closed](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) signal in your pipeline? this signal has a reason as argument.

Comment: Thank you! registering handler in pipeline it's good idea and it works for me. I edit post with a little snippet of working solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Hope to be conducive to you.

```
class SubJobPipeline(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ins = cls(crawler.settings)
        crawler.signals.connect(ins.customize_close_spider, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ins

    def customize_close_spider(self, **kwargs):
        _logger.warning("customize_close_spider kwargs: %s", kwargs)
        reason = kwargs.get("reason") # reason maybe finished, shutdown or others
        spider = kwargs.get("spider")
        if reason == "finished":
            # extract your item through spider
            # do what you want
```